# Python Protobuf SerializeToString needs an argument?

Tags: python, serialization, protocol-buffers

PythonCode:

```
import socket
from deviceReadout_pb2 import DeviceReadout
import protobuf3
import numpy as np
import threading

protocol = DeviceReadout()
protocol.ledStatus = msg
protocol.ledCount = len(ledStatus)               
        
toTransmit = protocol.SerializeToString()
```

Protobuf:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package readout;

message DeviceReadout
{
    bytes ledStatus = 1;
    int32 ledCount = 2;
}
```

[image: Error]

protocol is an Protobuf message. Calling SerializeToString gives me the error "unbound method CMessage.SerializeToString() needs an argument", but I haven't found any examples where an argument is needed for this method.
I'm using Protobuf3

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want `protocol = DeviceReadout()` to create a new instance of the class.

Please:

- Include a more representative subset of your code. In this case, your imports and the proto would help.
- Don't include screenshots (which may be deleted and can't be copied from) where it would be straightforward to copy-paste code

Comment: Edited Post and added Requested Information

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved:
Missing () after DeviceReadout and

```
protocol.ledStatus = msg
```

msg is an bytearray, so I had to convert it to bytes

```
protocol.ledStatus = bytes(msg)
```